# resizing (and moving?) partitions in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I'd like to use GParted (or fdisk) to go from the configuration in picture to one where I have the same ammount of space for swap and /, while /home eats all the remaining space. Is there a simple way to do that, perhaps using Ubuntu live CD?

(it's in Italian, but the meaning should be clear)

(I'm working in Ubuntu 12.04)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can unmount the `/home` and root partitions, you should be able to [move things around](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-move-partition) to your liking (perhaps using [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)).  I suggest deleting `sda4` and `sda5`, moving the `sda3` partition to the beginning of the disk, extending `sda2` to the remaining amount of free space less 954MiB, then creating swap space from the leftover.  If you do this, you will probably have to fix your GRUB menu since the location of your boot partition changed (I'm assuming it's on `sda3`).

Moving partitions around means the partition names probably won't reflect the physical location in the hard disk any more.  You can label the partitions and use labels or UUIDs in your `/etc/fstab`, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; so, just to recap, I could use Ubuntu live cd to start a gparted, then move and delete some partitions. About the grub story, what are exactly the commands I should run? some sudo update grub2 ? about the last point, do you mean I should also relabel partitions? can i do it in gparted?

Comment: You could probably use an Ubuntu Live CD, not sure if it has gparted on it. After you make all your changes, run something like `update-grub`; see [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd). As for the last point, it means you should at least check your `/etc/fstab`. If you label the partitions the same (which you can do in `gparted`), it might not need any changes.